# Trigger event in MVC Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

As you've known, it's very easy to trigger an event in WebForm, but it's a problem in MVC Framework. For example, I have 2 DropDownList, `Country` and `State`. I want to load the data in `State` base on selected `Country`. In WebForm, I can trigger the `SelectedIndexChange` event, but in MVC Framework, what should I do?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In WebForm, I can trigger the SelectedIndexChange event, but in MVC
>   Framework, what should I do?

You could use javascript and subscribe to the [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange) javascript event of the dropdown.

For example if you use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#id_of_your_drop_down').on('change', function() {
            // the value of the dropdown changed. Here you could do whatever
            // you intended to do. For example you could send the selected value
            // to a controller action using an AJAX call.
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction")';
            $.post(url, { value: selectedValue }, function(result) {
                // The AJAX request completed successfully. Here you could
                // do something with the results returned by the server
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please note that the example above relies on the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: May I suggest that the example use `.on('change', ...)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, using javascript is the only way? Do we have a way without using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: No, of course not. This is a client side event and the only way to subscribe to it is using javascript. By the way that's exactly how this was implemented in the WebForms world as well. Don't think that in the WebForms it was any different. They were just a leaky abstraction over HTTP and HTML. At the end of the day you feed your client browser HTML. Think in terms of that. Not in terms of server side frameworks.

Comment: @Forte_201092 the fundamental difference, view wise in `MVC` is that the view is a single file, a `cshtml` file. The Web Form version has code infront and code behind which you have access to the form, because it is your controller that returns a view, the controller isn't bound. This is known as being "loosely coupled", so the answer to your question is no :)